# Blur image on upload

Tags: javascript, image, blur

I'm developing a web application using Angular and Firebase. On the application, users can upload an image, and then other users can purchase that image. the problem is, I want to upload a blurred version of the image to Firebase storage so that I will have 2 versions of the image: the original image and the blurred image. once the user purchases the image he could download the original image.

I added a CSS property `filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.5);` but this is obviously bad practice since the users can either change the CSS property from the dev tools if they have some knowledge or just right click and `save image as` from the site and get the original one.

So my question is, what options do I have to blur the image ? in my opinion I should blur the image on upload so that I will have 2 versions of the image saved on storage so that a user can see the blurred version of the image before he purchase it.

Comment: and the question is ...?

Comment: @Henry well ... the question is how do I do that? lol

Comment: @KLTR the above question is a bit confusing. As I understood, you need a you need is a image processing lib. I would suggest to simply you question so it can be refer by later devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with **angular** or **firebase**. What you need is a **image processing node library**.

I would suggest to use -

- JIMP https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp
- lwip https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip
- Any other lib with good github stars

If you face any issue regarding their use, than share.